# Silverstripe 3.1.2 - PaginatedList only for Dataobjects related to page

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to create a paginated news section with different categories.
the problem is, that I get the news out of all categories and not only out of the chosen category.

My categories are pages and the news are stored in a Dataobject which has a $many_many relation.

That's my Code. What should i do to get only the "NewsObject" from the selected Page instead of all

```
public function Items() {
    if($this->Paginate) {
        $items = new PaginatedList(NewsObject::get()->filter(array(
            'Visibility' => 'true'
        )), $this->request);
        $items->setPageLength($this->ItemsPerPage);
    } else {
        $items = NewsObject::get()->filter(array(
            'Visibility' => 'true'
        ));
    }
    return $items;
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer my own question ...

just use $this->RelationName

```
// Show and Paginate Items
public function myItems() {
    if($this->Paginate) {
        $items = new PaginatedList($this->News()->filter(array(
            'Visibility' => 'true'
        )), $this->request);
        $items->setPageLength($this->ItemsPerPage);
    } else {
        $items = $this->News()->filter(array(
            'Visibility' => 'true'
        ));
    }
    return $items;
}
```